# Template function which generate random value from min to max of every type

Tags: c++, templates, math, random

i need to write template of function which gets type eg. int, and then it generates random value from MIN_INT to MAX_INT

```
template<typename TYPE>
TYPE generateRandom()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr)));
    TYPE generatedValue;
    //code :/
    return generatedValue;
}
```

few problems here:

- `rand` generate to0 small value (`RAND_MAX`)
- in `rand` i can't do `INT_MAX+1` to include int max and negative values

I tried also something like this:

```
std::random_device randomDevice;
std::mt19937_64 generator(randomDevice());

if(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::is_integer)
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<TYPE> dice(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(),std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
    generatedValue=dice(generator);
}
else
{
    std::uniform_real_distribution<TYPE> dice(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(),std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
    generatedValue=dice(generator);
}
```

but it didnt work :/

Comment: How did it not work?

Comment: i think it was sth with std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::is_integer cause when i was compiling and in main it was used with double it was crashing

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve] that duplicates the problem?

Comment: static assertion filed: template argument not an integral type :/

Comment: What version of C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: to be honest i dont understand this problem so much :/

i have second code in first one and this is in file file.h, when i use it in main generateRandom<float>(); it shows this problem

Comment: i tried on c++11 and c++14

Comment: You probably need `if constexpr` (C++17)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you have an `if/else` branch like you would use for run time value checks. You need compile time branching using template metaprogramming techniques.

Something along the lines of the following should work.

```
template <typename TYPE>
std::uniform_int_distribution<TYPE> getDice(std::true_type)
{
   return std::uniform_int_distribution<TYPE>(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
}

template <typename TYPE>
std::uniform_real_distribution<TYPE> getDice(std::false_type)
{
   return std::uniform_real_distribution<TYPE>(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
}

template<typename TYPE>
TYPE generateRandom()
{
   std::random_device randomDevice;
   std::mt19937_64 generator(randomDevice());
   auto dice = getDice<TYPE>(std::integral_constant<bool, std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::is_integer>());
   return dice(generator);
}
```

See it working at https://ideone.com/d7Ajfk.

If you are able to use C++17, you can use code that is similar to what you are trying by using `if constexpr`

```
template<typename TYPE>
TYPE generateRandom()
{
   std::random_device randomDevice;
   std::mt19937_64 generator(randomDevice());
   if constexpr ( std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::is_integer )
   {
      std::uniform_int_distribution<TYPE> dice(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
      return dice(generator);
   }
   else
   {
      std::uniform_real_distribution<TYPE> dice(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
      return dice(generator);
   }
}
```

Although, I would still encourage using a separate function `getDice()`

```
template <typename TYPE>
auto getDice(std::true_type)
{
   if constexpr ( std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::is_integer )
   {
      return std::uniform_int_distribution<TYPE>(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
   }
   else
   {
      return std::uniform_real_distribution<TYPE>(std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::min(), std::numeric_limits<TYPE>::max());
   }
}

template<typename TYPE>
TYPE generateRandom()
{
   std::random_device randomDevice;
   std::mt19937_64 generator(randomDevice());
   auto dice = getDice<TYPE>();
   return dice(generator);
}
```